# Creating a random that selects ONE integer

Tags: java, random

I need to make a random that selects ONE integer, all the code that I have tried generates 2 integers.  Here is my current code for a random int:

```
int randomInt = (int) (Math.random() * 6 + 1);
```

Help anyone?

Comment: what do you mean by this?  < 10?

Comment: The code above should generate either 1,2,4,5,6 or 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Gets a random integer in a given range inclusive
public static int getRand(int min, int max){
    return min + (int)(Math.random() * ((max - min) + 1));
}
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @JamesRobinson No, it will work for both! Why don't you try it?

Comment: This gives me 2 for some reason...  I'm confused, I've used all of thes e and I'm getting 2 nums...

Comment: I think I have a solution, but I don't know how to do it.  I need to set ONE of the integers to 0.

Comment: @user2653051 Run several times then. Calling with 1 and 6 will give you a number between 1 to 6. System.out.println(getRand(1, 6));

Comment: I'll try doing that again :P

Comment: It does output one number...  Thanks

Comment: @Sajal very sorry about that I misread the ()

Answer (score 0):

```
Random ran = new Random();
int number=ran.nextInt(20-10)+10;
```

This gives a random integer between 10 (inclusive) and 20 (exclusive).
Just only **one** random value.

Comment: Wrong, see JavaDoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)

Comment: it works fine in android.....

Comment: It will give you a random number between `0` (inclusive) and `10` (exclusive), because `20 - 10 = 10`

Comment: If you agree and fix the answer I'll remove my downvote.

Comment: this is what he was in need right? To get only one int

Comment: Yes, but you say your code generates an `int` between `10` and `20` and that is misleading.

Comment: ouch a number was missing in the code.. sorry +10 should have been appended... like int number=ran.nextInt(20-10)+10;

Comment: removed my downvote. What you have now is a complicated way of writing `ran.nextInt(10) + 10;` (P.S. Use backticks `\`` to mark code inside the comments.)